# Is dehydration of cobalt(II) chloride hexahydrate dynamic equilibrium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, solid-state-chemistry

I know that the dehydration of cobalt(II) chloride hexahydrate is a reversible reaction, is it a dynamic equilibrium?

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CoCl2·6H2O &<=> CoCl2·2H2O + 4 H2O}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{CoCl2·2H2O &<=> CoCl2 + 2 H2O}\tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

Some sources say that it is, but others say that it isn't because the forward and reverse reactions don't occur spontaneously. If it is not a dynamic equilibrium, is it considered a chemical equilibrium? Would be great if someone could please clarify.

Comment: I assume you mean dehydration as a state,  not a process. For given T and partial water vapor pressure, there is an equilibrium state of a particular hydration degree. Higher T or lower vapor pressure lead to higher dehydration and vice verse.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason you are asking about this very compound? Otherwise I suppose the question could be extended to pretty much all inorganic crystallohydrates.

Comment: This was just a common example I saw in my textbooks, but I assume that you should be right to say that this question could apply to other inorganic crystallohydrates.

Comment: This compound is used to show a chemical equilibrium in classroom. Dissolving $\ce{CoCl2·6H2O}$ in ethanol produces a blue solution, due to  $$\ce{2 [Co(H2O)6]Cl2 -> [Co(H2O)6]^{2+} + [CoCl4]^{2+} + 6 H2O}$$  The hydrated ion $\ce{Co(H2O)6]^{2+}}$ is pale red. As the complex $\ce{[CoCl4]^{2-}}$ has a dark blue color,  the ethanol solution of $\ce{CoCl2·6H2O}$ is blue. But adding a few drops water, the solution turns red, due to  $$\ce{[CoCl4]^{2-} + 6 H2O <=> [Co(H2O)6]^{2+}  +  4 Cl-}$$. Now heating the solution turns it blue again, by reversing the last equation. And red again by cooling.

Comment: And CoCl2 on blotting paper is a classical humidity indicator in air, showing the equilibrium *does* shift with a change in environment.